# Python SQL score reader

Tags: python, sql, database, list, sqlite

I have a function within my "students' test" program.

This function reads out either the "highest score", "lowest score" or "average score" when you enter the student's name and class number.

The first two parts work but i can't seem to get the average working, when i read a value from a database it never returns like i would prefer it to, it returns it like: [(6,) , (3,)].

This is the function below:

```
def readScore():
selection = input("What score would you like the read ? \n 1 - Lowest score \n 2 - Highest score \n 3 - Average score... ")
name = input("Please enter the name of the pupil...")
classNo = input("Please enter the class of the pupil...")

myFile = sqlite3.connect("scores.db")
c = myFile.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT score FROM scores WHERE name = (?) AND classNo = (?)', (name, classNo,))
row = c.fetchall()
print(row)

try:
    if selection == "1":
        print (min(row))
    if selection == "2":
        print (max(row))
    if selection == "3":
        print (sum(row) /len(row))
except:
    print("No scores for that student")

myFile.commit()
myFile.close()
```

Comment: The code you have posted is too much. Please consider producing minimal code to reproduce your bug.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* compute the average in your program, but it would be a better idea to avoid fetching all rows, and to [let the database compute](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) these values:

```
c.execute('SELECT MIN(score) FROM ...')   # or
c.execute('SELECT MAX(score) FROM ...')   # or
c.execute('SELECT AVG(score) FROM ...')
row = c.fetchone()
print(row[0])
```